# Changing image color in NavLink button React

Tags: reactjs, router

I am wonder how to change image when `NavLink` is active.
So far I wrote this :

```
            <li className={(active==='adminPanel') ? styles.LeftMenuActiveLink : null }
            onClick={()=>changeActive('adminPanel')}
            style={{color: '#69B4D6'}}>
            <NavLink   to="/adminPanel">
                <img 
                    src={(active==='adminPanel')? NotificationsImageActive : NotificationsImage} 
                    alt="notification icon" width="60px" height="60px" />
                <span >Panel Admina</span>
            </NavLink>
        </li>
```

where active variable is in my state. This works, but refreshing page destroy it. I am wonder if I can check somehow if `NavLink` is active and with this information set my `src` in `<img />`

Working version :

```
<li>
                <NavLink onClick={() => setPath("/events")} activeClassName={styles.LoggedLeftMenuActiveLink} to="/events">
                    <img
                        src={(window.location.pathname === "/events") ? EventsImageActive : EventsImage}
                        alt="events icon" width="60px" height="60px" />
                    Wydarzenia
                </NavLink>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check something like 
`location.pathname == "adminPanel"`
so it will work even when your page is reloaded/refreshed.

Comment: Yea it works, but my Navbar doesn't re-render so I have to refresh page now to get desirable effect.

Comment: I have posted the answer which is to be used in addition to your code, as you said it is already working and only destroys when page is refreshed. So keep the source of truth in your state and handle it for page refresh with location.pathname.Let me know further

Comment: I don't know if I understand what do you mean.. I wrote onClick event on my <li> element which should change the state and because of that my component should re-render, but I don't know why this didn't work...

Comment: Ok I had one mistake in code in solution from my lastest comment. But when did it like I said above, that works :P Maybe even you thought about the same solution :P

Comment: so u mean to say its completely working now? or in the previous condition?

Comment: It works. I added working code in the main question.